# Show IP Address and IP Address Count Per Hour from Apache Logs

Tags: bash, apache, logging, awk, gawk

How do I use awk to parse the Apache access log file to display information in the following format?

```
   Date     Time  Count   IP Address
2016-05-26  00:00  200    192.168.1.x
2016-05-26  00:00  152    172.17.100.x
2016-05-26  00:01   43    192.168.1.x
```

Let me be clear. I **do not** want to show total requests per hour. I **do not** want to show total requests per minute. I know how to write basic awk scripts to perform both of those tasks.

I **want** to see how many requests per minute each **unique** IP address is sending. I'm not savvy enough with awk to do this.

**Apache Log Format**

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %{%F %T %z}t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\""
```

**Sample**

I tailed the end of the log file. Here's a small sample of what it contains. (We have over 100K entries for today. It's not feasible to share them all here. If more lines are needed please ask.)

```
54.213.236.39 - - 2016-05-26 14:38:51 -0400 "GET /p1077921.html HTTP/1.0" 403 400 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/1.8.0_77)"
54.213.236.39 - - 2016-05-26 14:38:51 -0400 "GET /p1060432.html HTTP/1.0" 403 398 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/1.8.0_77)"
54.213.254.166 - - 2016-05-26 14:38:51 -0400 "GET /p819757.html HTTP/1.0" 403 400 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/1.8.0_77)"
54.213.236.39 - - 2016-05-26 14:38:51 -0400 "GET /p1084269.html HTTP/1.0" 403 400 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/1.8.0_77)"
107.23.252.229 - - 2016-05-26 14:38:51 -0400 "GET /p305987.html HTTP/1.0" 403 399 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/1.8.0_77)"
```

**Example 1:**

```
grep '2016-05-26' access.log | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | tail -40 | awk '{print $2,$2,$1}' | logresolve | awk '{printf "%6d %s (%s)\n",$3,$1,$2}'
```

Produces the following output

```
307 135-23-174-138.cpe.pppoe.ca (135.23.174.138)
313 5265DCE5.cm-8.dynamic.ziggo.nl (82.101.220.229)
378 92-108-204-76.dynamic.upc.nl (92.108.204.76)
405 0191301456.0.fullrate.ninja (90.185.180.167)
632 ec2-52-58-151-132.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com (52.58.151.132)
798 187.228.212.148 (187.228.212.148)
877 207.246.75.253 (207.246.75.253)
966 ec2-54-213-177-120.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com (54.213.177.120)
1116 ec2-54-186-148-0.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com (54.186.148.0)
1224 ppp121-44-247-209.bras2.syd2.internode.on.net (121.44.247.209)
1369 ec2-54-187-239-46.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com (54.187.239.46)
1584 45.55.189.64 (45.55.189.64)
2658 50-77-47-70-static.hfc.comcastbusiness.net (50.77.47.70)
```

**Example 2:**

```
grep "2016-05-26" access.log | awk '{ print $4, $5, $1}' | cut -f2 | awk -F: '{ print $1":"$2 }' | sort -nk1 -nk2 | uniq -c | awk '{ if ($1 > 10) print $0 }'
```

That gives the following output:

```
560 2016-05-26 00:00
534 2016-05-26 00:01
538 2016-05-26 00:02
554 2016-05-26 00:03
566 2016-05-26 00:04
534 2016-05-26 00:05
559 2016-05-26 00:06
531 2016-05-26 00:07
540 2016-05-26 00:08
435 2016-05-26 00:09
312 2016-05-26 00:10
```

All help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Please show your coding efforts.

Comment: we can't help you achieve a **better understanding** of `awk` without being able to assess your *current understanding*, which is best illustrated by code that shows your best attempt to solve your current problem. AND to do that in an efficient manner, we'll need some small sample data, required output from that sample data (which you have provided), but also your current output from your current code AND/OR any error messages that are being generated by your current code (hence a reasonable request for http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ). Please update your Q and people can help. Good luck.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a "please write code for me" site. Your requirements are reasonable but this is off-topic here.

Comment: As is, you're currently ask "someone who has a better understanding of the awk command than I do" to do it for you, and (while it happens every day here on S.O.), it is not really a proper expectation of the S.O. community.  Good luck.

Comment: _I'm asking someone who has a better understanding of the awk command than I do to show me how to use the awk command to do what I've asked_. Sure... [here you go](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html)...

Comment: I apologize for my comments from earlier. Right now I'm dealing with something that appears to be a DoS attack on my employer's webserver. We're an e-commerce company. Staying available for our customers is very important for us. I added examples. Please help me write better awk.

Comment: [edit] your question to simply show some concise, testable sample input and expected output. Right now you've shown us a couple of command that reads an input file and apparently produce some output that is not what you want and you've told us what you want but you haven't shown us the input file. Telling us a format for it is fine if that's in addition to sample data but not instead of sample data.

Comment: I added a sample containing the last 5 lines from the access.log file.

Comment: OK you've added sample input, now add the expected output given that input and then we can stop trying to hep you ask your question and move on to trying to help you solve your problem.

Comment: I just noticed you're asking for output that's a count per minute but all of your sample input occurs with exactly the same timestamp to the second so that's a very poor sample. Put some effort into creating a sample input file that will help demonstrate and test a potential solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

here's a way:

first, convert this:

```
54.213.236.39 - - 2016-05-26 14:38:51 -0400 "GET /p1077921.html HTTP/1.0" 403 400 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/1.8.0_77)"
```

to this:

```
54.213.236.39 2016-05-26 14  # <- 14th hour
```

then `sort | uniq -c` that.

```
grep '2016-05-26' access.log |
  tr ':' ' ' |
  awk '{print $1,$4,$5}' |
  sort |
  uniq -c |
  sort -n
```